# Unable to create FileWriter

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to create a FileWriter instance pointing to a folder were everyone has write access:

```
new FileWriter("C:\\Temp\java_play\\temp")
```

And I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException with detail message:

```
"C:\Temp\java_play\temp (Access is denied)"
```

The folder exists and if I stop in debugger and evaluate expression below it always returns true as it should:

```
new File("C:\\Temp\java_play\\temp").canWrite()
```

I don't understand what is going on. I am using intelij and I have Windows 7 operating system and I am trying to run this using Java 8.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the difference between normal file and others (folder, link, and some other type of directory entries?)

Comment: Windows won't allow a process to open a file for writing if any other process already has it open. Could that be what's happening? https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-process-locked-file-openfiles-utility/

Comment: As you can see in my code example I am trying to open a `FileWriter` instance pointing to a folder. I don't think such a restriction would apply in this case.

Comment: In that case, the problem is that you can’t create a `FileWriter` instance pointing to a folder. It needs to be a normal file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reported expected behaviour . On Windows any attempt to write to a directory with `FileWriter` will fail, giving access denied:

```
File folder = new File("C:\\Temp\java_play\\temp");
System.out.println("folder.isDirectory()="+folder.isDirectory()+" folder.canWrite()="+folder.canWrite());
// prints "folder.isDirectory()=true folder.canWrite()=true"

System.out.println("new FileWriter("+folder+")="+new FileWriter(folder));
// reports Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Temp\java_play\temp (Access is denied)
```

Changing the path to a file within the folder should work fine as long as the filename provided is writable:

```
File file   = new File(folder, "file"+System.nanoTime()+".xyz");
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file)) {
   // no exception
}
```